# Slim Framework GetHeaders from Post Request

Tags: post, http-headers, slim

I am sending a token in header and I want that token for JWT authentication. How can I get the headers passed. Body I am getting in

$data using below code

```
$request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
$data = json_decode($request->getBody());
```

I need the headers sent in post.

```
require 'Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->post('/staff','getStaff');
$app->run();

function getStaff() {
    $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();

    $data = json_decode($request->getBody());
    $header = $request->getBasePath();

    // echo $header;
    print_r( $header);
    print_r( $data);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

$header = $app->request->headers->get('Content-Type');

I got the answer. My version of Slim was 2.4 and I figured it out from old documentation.

Pass the header key you want, in my case it was Token

$header = $app->request->headers->get('Token');

Now I will get the token passed through headers